# How do I compare latency and timeouts at server side between two Aerospike clusters of different versions - 3.8 and 3.14?

Tags: performance, timeout, latency, aerospike, asgraphite

I have two aerospike clusters running community editions -

- Older cluster with the servers having the following combinations -
       storing data in disk + i2.2xlarge instances + Aerospike build vesion 3.8.2.3
- Newer cluster with the servers having the following combinations -
       storing data in memory + r3.4xlarge instances + Aerospike build version 3.14.1.1 + using partition-tree-sprigs

I wanted to compare the server side latencies and timeouts on them.
I enabled the asgraphite daemon which comes in-built with Aerospike, by the following command -

```
python /opt/aerospike/bin/asgraphite --start --prefix aerospike.stats -g <URL> -p <port>
```

I cannot see the latency stats against the old cluster in the graphite console (see highlight in screenshot) -

[image]

Also, I am confused, as to which latency stat should I consider.
Following stats are available against  the older cluster -

```
Metric                               Value observed on one node
batch_index_timeout                  0
batch_timeout                        0
err_tsvc_requests_timeout            ~80K
stat_rw_timeout                      ~500K
```

The batch stats are showing 0, as expected, because we are not doing any batch queries. The new cluster being higher than 3.9 does not have the `err_tsvc_requests_timeout` and `stat_rw_timeout` metrics.

[The relevant manual page of aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics) mentions against the deprecated metrics -

> As of version 3.9, refer to the more specific stats at the namespace
>   level.

Not sure which are those.

**Opening Bounty**

The [metrics reference manual](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics) mentions against metric`stat_rw_timeout` -

> As of version 3.9, refer to the more specific stats at the namespace
>   level.

I am expecting the same to be reflected against the namespace value in the graphite web console, but all I can see are the following - ops_per_sec, over_1ms, over_64ms etc.

[image]

So, basically I am looking for two things now -

- Exact meaning of some stat/metric getting moved to namespace level. How can it be viewed in graphite web console, it at all it can be seen.
- More pointers towards selecting the appropriate metrics for latency and timeout across both the versions. I am working on the common use case of reading and writing aerospike cache keys via the PHP client API functions -

  Aerospike->get()
  Aerospike->put()

**Update 2**

*timeouts -* Finally, I am able to locate the reorganized timeout related parameters in the new build version, as explained in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244090/351903. 
But, the values client_write_timeout etc being cumulative, are difficult to compare across clusters, as logging might have started earlier in one of the clusters. It would have been better to have an instantaneous metric for timeouts.

[image]

**Update 3**

*latency -* Since I did not get latency stats in graphite web console for build version less than 3.9, I am planning to use asloglatency and dump the stats to graphite server for both the build versions.
To uniformly compare latencies in a graphical way, I have planned to -

- Setup a cron which runs every 5 mins.
- Run the asloglatency command to collect the following latency stats for 2 minutes duration, starting from last 5 minutes for both the build versions -

  - avg of - % greater than 1 ms, 8 and 64 ms and ops per second.
  - maximum of - % greater than 1 ms, 8 and 64 ms and ops per second.

Asloglatency command for Version > 3.9

```
asloglatency -N FC -h write -f -0:05:00 -d 0:60:00
asloglatency -N FC -h read -f -0:05:00 -d 0:60:00
```

Command for Version < 3.9

```
asloglatency -h writes_master -f -0:05:00 -d 2:00
asloglatency -h reads -f -0:05:00 -d 2:00
```

Note - I got latency stats for new build by running asgraphite command -

```
python /opt/aerospike/bin/asgraphite --start -g <domain> -p <port>
```

But I am not sure which of the above stats are logged in case of new build under `{HOSTNAME}.latency` in graphite console - avg or max values. I did not find any documentation of the same in the metrics reference manual. 
[image]

Also, the above command did not show latency stats in graphite console for older build.

Hopefully, the stats derived using asloglatency will be uniform across the two build versions.

***Via open bounty - Looking for confirmations that this would work/would be the best way to do what I am trying to find out/pointers to easier ways of doing the same.***

**Update 4**

*1. Timeout*

I am able to get instantaneous timeouts on old build by applying derivative() on the graph obtained by logging `stat_rw_timeout` -

```
http://<domain>/render?width=1700&from=-6h&until=now&height=900&target=derivative(aerospike.old_statsip-10-146-210-31.service.stat_rw_timeout)&title=old_latency_cumulative_derivative&hideLegend=false&_salt=1367201670.479&yMax=&_uniq=0.985620767407021
```

[image]

**However, timeouts on new build are showing 0** consistently even though `client_read_success` is showing values -
[image]

*2. Latency*

Looks like the following asgraphite command logs latency in both the build versions, so I will not need to do all those stuff using asloglatency as I mentioned in my **Update 3** -

```
python /opt/aerospike/bin/asgraphite -l 'latency:' --start --prefix aerospike.temp.old_trial1 -g <graphite server domain> -p <port>
```

The values I am monitoring are -

New build -

```
aerospike.temp.new_trial2ip-10-13-215-20.latency.FC.read.over_1ms
aerospike.temp.new_trial2ip-10-13-215-20.latency.FC.write.over_1ms
```

Old build -

```
aerospike.temp.old_trial1ip-10-182-71-216.latency.reads.over_1ms
aerospike.temp.old_trial1ip-10-182-71-216.latency.writes_master.over_1ms
```

Here are the results observed from the graphs -

- Read latency on new build - consistently 0.
- Write latency on new build - only one spike, otherwise consistently 0.
- Read and write latency on old build - consistent data.

**Update 5**

I just want to make I am comparing the right metrics for latency and timeouts comparison across the build versions. Can someone point me to some documentation related to the same?

Latency - I have mentioned the values I am comparing in update 4 above. Following is their hierarchy in the graphite web console -

[image]

Timeouts - There is no direct mention in the metrics reference manual that `stat_rw_timeout` splits into `client_read_timeout` and `client_write_timeout` in version 3.9. Can someone confirm the same?

I am having above concerns/queries because of the following conclusions from my observations -

[image]

Comment: You can perform derivatives on metrics in graphite, so being cumulative shouldn't prevent you from retrieving the rate. Instantaneous may be 'better' for your case but it isn't in general (cumulative can answer rates for arbitrary intervals, as well as did it happen since start). I agree if you are only interested in the rate than a rate would be convenient to have, however I don't think this marginal convenience would justify doubling the number of metrics.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, the best resource is the [metrics reference manual](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics) in the deployment section of the Aerospike docs. Locate the older, deprecated stat, and the description will tell you what the equivalent post [release 3.9](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/aerospike-3-9-release/) metric is called.

The [Stats and Benchmark Migration Guide for the 3.9 Release](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/upgrade/stats_to_3_9) details the different statistics.

Specifically to latency, [Histograms from Aerospike Logs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/monitor/latency) has the breakdown of the latency histograms post-3.9, with the [pre-3.9 latency histograms](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/monitor/latency/pre3_9/latency_pre3_9.html) in a separate article.

Comment: Could not correlate things still. Added bounty to question and more details. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 4):

A convenient list of almost every stat and where they moved can be found in the schema file for our collectd plugin:

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-collectd/blob/develop/aerospike_schema.yaml

[Comment added here:]
Specifically for stat_rw_timeout:

It was originally under `service.stat_rw_timeout`.
It is now split up to be client_read_timeout and client_write_timeout. It is under the `namespace` section.

So in Graphite, it would have moved from
aerospike.{HOSTNAME}.service.stat_rw_timeout to:

aerospike.{HOSTNAME}.{NAMESPACE}.client_write_timeout and
aerospike.{HOSTNAME}.{NAMESPACE}.client_read_timeout.

Now this also means you'd need to add `-n` to your asgraphite parameters, since you're monitoring namespace metrics.

Don't look under the latency section (aerospike.{HOSTNAME}.latency).

Comment: I can locate a lot of the metrics, e.g. aggr_scans_failed in the graphite web console, against the instances with older build, but I cannot locate the ones which have been moved to some namespace. I am missing something. Could you please add some specific details considering one metric? I have added bounty to the question and added more details.

Comment: Finally I have been able to locate the timeout related reorganized parameters. So, upvoted the answer. But, this timeout value seems to be a cumulative sum of all the timeouts (Attached a graph of stat_rw_timeout in update 2 of question). I have written about the difficulties faced due to that.

Comment: Regarding latency, please see my update 3 and see if you can help.

Comment: Just a heads up, the latency benchmarks may not be apples to apples when comparing 3.9- to 3.9+. IIRC the refinements mainly affected microbemchmarks - so the read and write benchmarks you are observing are probably equivalent... But if you notice a significant difference you may want to verify that the difference is also measurable from the client.

Comment: Your bounty and original question has been answered. Please ask another question instead of appending followup questions as updates, or post to our forums at discuss.aerospike.com as you have before.

Answer (score 3):

There was a stat/log reorg in 3.9, the metric reference page should provide where they were moved. Some stats/histograms were refined to only measure what they were meant to measure so comparing pre 3.9 stats to post 3.9 may not be apples to apples.

Noticed a typo on the metrics page for **err_tsvc_requests_timeout**, it should have directed you to **client_tsvc_timout**.

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics#client_tsvc_timeout

Comment: I can see the metric `err_tsvc_requests_timeout` in the graphite web console against the instances with old build (I have attached screenshots of the console in my question), but I cannot see the metric `client_tsvc_timout` against the instances with new build.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs so far. Regarding latency, please see my update 3 in question and see if you can help.